# Query for only nested associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the follow set up in my models:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :plans
end

class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :documents
end

class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
end
```

I'm trying to make a query in which I can easily return all nested associated records. For example, I want to be able to do something like: `Project.documents` and get all documents for a project. I've tried this with an `includes` like so:

```
Project.includes({plans: [:documents]})
```

but that doesn't appear to give me what I want when I call `Project.documents`. I really only want all documents for a project, so don't really need to include plans. Is there an easy way todo this in Rails 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between a *document* and a *plan* goes first through *project*, so you can use `joins`, specifying that a *document* belongs to a *plan*, and that a *plan* belongs to a *project*. After that you can filter the rows by selecting the *plans* (whose *document* belongs to) having the `project_id` equals `...`:

```
Document.joins(plan: :project).where(plans: { project_id: ... })
```